How to use nvim-rip-substitute to make replacments?
I am using Neovim with the plugin nvim-rip-substitute.  The problem is when I try to replace foo with bar it will change for all the lines where foo is.
How can I limit the replacement to for example to the first or to the second lines ?
1. The foo is here
2. And foo also here
3. And foo also here

with:
1. The bar is here
2. And bar also here
3. And foo also here

or:
1. The bar is here
2. And foo also here
3. And bar also here

A second problem is how can I search and replace in a line the words foo and bar with foo2 and bar2 like:
The foo and the bar 

With:
The foo2 and the bar2


IMHO, the problem with many plugins is that they're trying to reinvent the wheel. Learn the basics first, then decide whether you really need a plugin to replace the :substitute command.

Let me rephrase my earlier comment in a more constructive way: you should read :help pattern to learn about regular expressions. There's also a wealth of online resources. Yes, there are different regex dialects but the basics are the same and differ mostly in which special characters you have to backslash-escape.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest :-)

For the first you could do to replace only of the second line:
You could do:
In standard Vim:
2s/foo/bar/g

With rip-substitute:
2RipSubstitute
search: foo
replace: bar

For the second you could do:
In standard Vim:
%s/\v(foo|bar)/\02/g

With rip-substitute:
search: (foo|bar)
replace: $02

To replace foo...bar by animal...house you could do:
In standard Vim:
%s/\vfoo(.*)bar/animal\1house/

With rip-substitute:
search: foo(.*)bar
replace animal$1house

Remark: provided that you use the supermagic flag (\v) you will notice that the two syntaxes are very close ($1 -> \1)

« Teach them to fish »: where could they have learned this information and more?

That's working and how do I  search and replace foo and bar with animal and house for example.  So (foo..bar) become (animal..house) wit rip-substitute ?
